# How to parse from string?

Tags: python

I have string with tags "Key", I need get text inside tags.

```
string = "<Key>big_img/1/V071-e.jpg</Key>"
```

Need `"big_img/1/V071-e.jpg"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Are there any nested tags?

Comment: This is xml. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "<Key>big_img/1/V071-e.jpg</Key>"

re.findall(r"<Key>(.*)</Key>",s)
['big_img/1/V071-e.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution:

```
string.trim()[5:-6]
```

This will work for any length string provided it starts with `<Key>` and ends with `</Key>`.

It works because:

- `trim()` removes any extraneous whitespace characters
- `<Key>` will always be in the first 5 chars of the string, so start 1 char after (remember sequence/string indexes are 0-based, so starting at 5 is really starting at the 6th char)
- the beginning of `</Key>` will always be 6 chars from the end of the string, so stop before that point

Comment: I have big string with many `<Key></Key>`. I need do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module to parse your XML string. If your file looks something like:

```xml
<root>
    <Key>big_img/1/V071-e.jpg</Key>
    <Key>big_img/1/V072-e.jpg</Key>
    <Key>big_img/1/V073-e.jpg</Key>
    <Key>...</Key>
</root>
```

First, parse your data:

```python
from xml.etree import ElementTree

# To parse the data from a string.
doc = ElementTree.fromstring(data_string)

# Or, to parse the data from a file.
doc = ElementTree.parse('data.xml')
```

Then, read and print out the text from each `<Key>`:

```python
for key_element in doc.findall('Key'):
    print(key_element.text)
```

Should output:

```
big_img/1/V071-e.jpg
big_img/1/V072-e.jpg
big_img/1/V073-e.jpg
```